# How do I get specific values from API?

Tags: python, api, flask

I have the following code:

```
# Example page
@app.route('/example')
def example():

    # Example of API call to get deals
    base_url = "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/"
    params = "?_limit=50"
    url = base_url + params
    response_deals = get_api_data(headers=headers, url=url)

    """
    [YOUR CODE HERE]
    In this exmaple, this is where you can do something with the data in
    'response_deals' before you return it below.
    """

    if len(response_deals) > 0:
        return render_template('example.html', deals=response_deals)
    else:
        msg = 'No deals found'
        return render_template('example.html', msg=msg)
```

I am trying to get just the values called 'value' from the API. What kind of code would I need to use to do that?

The output from the API is:

```
{"_links": {"self": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/"}, "next": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/?_offset=10"}}, "_embedded": {"limeobjects": [{"dealstatus": {"id": 15101, "key": "agreement", "text": "4. Agreement"}, "value": 500000.0, "quotesent": "2016-08-25T00:00:00+02:00", "expecteddate": "2016-08-01T00:00:00+02:00", "closeddate": "2019-06-05T00:00:00+02:00", "person": 1052, "coworker": 1003, "wonlostreason": "", "company": 1002, "name": "Big business", "probability": 1.0, "weightedvalue": 500000.0, "todo2": null, "_id": 1001, "_timestamp": "2021-03-24T20:33:53.807000+01:00", "_descriptive": "Big business", "_updateduser": 1701, "_createduser": 1, "_createdtime": "2016-06-27T14:43:41.657000+02:00", "_links": {"limetype": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limetype/deal/", "name": "deal"}, "self": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1001/"}, "relation_person": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1001/person/", "name": "person"}, "relation_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1001/document/", "name": "document"}, "relation_coworker": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1001/coworker/", "name": "coworker"}, "relation_company": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1001/company/", "name": "company"}, "relation_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1001/history/", "name": "history"}, "relation_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1001/todo/", "name": "todo"}, "relation_todo2": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1001/todo2/", "name": "todo2"}, "new_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1001/document/new/"}, "new_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1001/history/new/"}, "new_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1001/todo/new/"}}}, {"dealstatus": {"id": 15001, "key": "tender", "text": "3. Quote"}, "value": 2999992.0, "quotesent": "2014-12-22T00:00:00+01:00", "expecteddate": null, "closeddate": "2019-05-22T00:00:00+02:00", "person": 1014, "coworker": null, "wonlostreason": "2015-02-28", "company": 1010, "name": "CRM-system, LIME Pro", "probability": 0.41, "weightedvalue": 1229996.0, "todo2": null, "_id": 1010, "_timestamp": "2020-06-04T22:03:00.300000+02:00", "_descriptive": "CRM-system, LIME Pro", "_updateduser": 1701, "_createduser": 1, "_createdtime": "2016-09-15T10:16:25.677000+02:00", "_links": {"limetype": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limetype/deal/", "name": "deal"}, "self": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1010/"}, "relation_person": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1010/person/", "name": "person"}, "relation_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1010/document/", "name": "document"}, "relation_coworker": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1010/coworker/", "name": "coworker"}, "relation_company": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1010/company/", "name": "company"}, "relation_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1010/history/", "name": "history"}, "relation_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1010/todo/", "name": "todo"}, "relation_todo2": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1010/todo2/", "name": "todo2"}, "new_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1010/document/new/"}, "new_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1010/history/new/"}, "new_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1010/todo/new/"}}}, {"dealstatus": {"id": 15101, "key": "agreement", "text": "4. Agreement"}, "value": 500.0, "quotesent": "2015-09-14T00:00:00+02:00", "expecteddate": null, "closeddate": "2019-12-19T00:00:00+01:00", "person": 1009, "coworker": null, "wonlostreason": "2015-09-19", "company": 1013, "name": "CRM f\u00f6r byggbolag", "probability": 1.0, "weightedvalue": 500.0, "todo2": null, "_id": 1011, "_timestamp": "2019-12-17T21:38:05.650000+01:00", "_descriptive": "CRM f\u00f6r byggbolag", "_updateduser": 1701, "_createduser": 1, "_createdtime": "2016-09-15T10:16:25.973000+02:00", "_links": {"limetype": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limetype/deal/", "name": "deal"}, "self": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1011/"}, "relation_person": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1011/person/", "name": "person"}, "relation_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1011/document/", "name": "document"}, "relation_coworker": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1011/coworker/", "name": "coworker"}, "relation_company": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1011/company/", "name": "company"}, "relation_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1011/history/", "name": "history"}, "relation_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1011/todo/", "name": "todo"}, "relation_todo2": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1011/todo2/", "name": "todo2"}, "new_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1011/document/new/"}, "new_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1011/history/new/"}, "new_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1011/todo/new/"}}}, {"dealstatus": {"id": 15101, "key": "agreement", "text": "4. Agreement"}, "value": 500000.0, "quotesent": "2016-03-11T00:00:00+01:00", "expecteddate": null, "closeddate": "2018-10-04T00:00:00+02:00", "person": 1010, "coworker": null, "wonlostreason": "", "company": 1029, "name": "Supertech Deal", "probability": 1.0, "weightedvalue": 500000.0, "todo2": null, "_id": 1012, "_timestamp": "2019-06-05T11:21:23.030000+02:00", "_descriptive": "Supertech Deal", "_updateduser": 1701, "_createduser": 1, "_createdtime": "2016-09-15T10:16:26.130000+02:00", "_links": {"limetype": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limetype/deal/", "name": "deal"}, "self": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1012/"}, "relation_person": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1012/person/", "name": "person"}, "relation_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1012/document/", "name": "document"}, "relation_coworker": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1012/coworker/", "name": "coworker"}, "relation_company": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1012/company/", "name": "company"}, "relation_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1012/history/", "name": "history"}, "relation_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1012/todo/", "name": "todo"}, "relation_todo2": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1012/todo2/", "name": "todo2"}, "new_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1012/document/new/"}, "new_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1012/history/new/"}, "new_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1012/todo/new/"}}}, {"dealstatus": {"id": 15101, "key": "agreement", "text": "4. Agreement"}, "value": 500000.0, "quotesent": "2016-03-12T00:00:00+01:00", "expecteddate": null, "closeddate": "2018-10-04T00:00:00+02:00", "person": 1036, "coworker": null, "wonlostreason": "", "company": 1016, "name": "Superaff\u00e4ren", "probability": 1.0, "weightedvalue": 500000.0, "todo2": null, "_id": 1013, "_timestamp": "2019-06-05T11:21:23.030000+02:00", "_descriptive": "Superaff\u00e4ren", "_updateduser": 1701, "_createduser": 1, "_createdtime": "2016-09-15T10:16:26.257000+02:00", "_links": {"limetype": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limetype/deal/", "name": "deal"}, "self": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1013/"}, "relation_person": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1013/person/", "name": "person"}, "relation_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1013/document/", "name": "document"}, "relation_coworker": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1013/coworker/", "name": "coworker"}, "relation_company": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1013/company/", "name": "company"}, "relation_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1013/history/", "name": "history"}, "relation_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1013/todo/", "name": "todo"}, "relation_todo2": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1013/todo2/", "name": "todo2"}, "new_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1013/document/new/"}, "new_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1013/history/new/"}, "new_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1013/todo/new/"}}}, {"dealstatus": {"id": 15101, "key": "agreement", "text": "4. Agreement"}, "value": 500000.0, "quotesent": "2016-04-17T00:00:00+02:00", "expecteddate": null, "closeddate": "2018-10-04T00:00:00+02:00", "person": 1026, "coworker": null, "wonlostreason": "", "company": 1021, "name": "LEGO Big Deal!", "probability": 1.0, "weightedvalue": 500000.0, "todo2": null, "_id": 1014, "_timestamp": "2019-06-05T11:21:23.030000+02:00", "_descriptive": "LEGO Big Deal!", "_updateduser": 1701, "_createduser": 1, "_createdtime": "2016-09-15T10:16:26.397000+02:00", "_links": {"limetype": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limetype/deal/", "name": "deal"}, "self": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1014/"}, "relation_person": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1014/person/", "name": "person"}, "relation_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1014/document/", "name": "document"}, "relation_coworker": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1014/coworker/", "name": "coworker"}, "relation_company": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1014/company/", "name": "company"}, "relation_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1014/history/", "name": "history"}, "relation_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1014/todo/", "name": "todo"}, "relation_todo2": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1014/todo2/", "name": "todo2"}, "new_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1014/document/new/"}, "new_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1014/history/new/"}, "new_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1014/todo/new/"}}}, {"dealstatus": {"id": 15401, "key": "rejection", "text": "Rejection"}, "value": 500000.0, "quotesent": null, "expecteddate": null, "closeddate": "2018-10-04T00:00:00+02:00", "person": 1008, "coworker": 1003, "wonlostreason": "", "company": 1028, "name": "Tobleroneaff\u00e4ren", "probability": 0.0, "weightedvalue": 0.0, "todo2": null, "_id": 1015, "_timestamp": "2021-05-25T23:58:34.440000+02:00", "_descriptive": "Tobleroneaff\u00e4ren", "_updateduser": 1701, "_createduser": 1, "_createdtime": "2016-09-15T10:16:26.550000+02:00", "_links": {"limetype": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limetype/deal/", "name": "deal"}, "self": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1015/"}, "relation_person": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1015/person/", "name": "person"}, "relation_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1015/document/", "name": "document"}, "relation_coworker": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1015/coworker/", "name": "coworker"}, "relation_company": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1015/company/", "name": "company"}, "relation_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1015/history/", "name": "history"}, "relation_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1015/todo/", "name": "todo"}, "relation_todo2": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1015/todo2/", "name": "todo2"}, "new_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1015/document/new/"}, "new_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1015/history/new/"}, "new_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1015/todo/new/"}}}, {"dealstatus": {"id": 15101, "key": "agreement", "text": "4. Agreement"}, "value": 500000.0, "quotesent": null, "expecteddate": null, "closeddate": "2019-10-04T00:00:00+02:00", "person": 1012, "coworker": null, "wonlostreason": "", "company": 1019, "name": "LIME Pro - 6 anv\u00e4ndare", "probability": 1.0, "weightedvalue": 500000.0, "todo2": null, "_id": 1016, "_timestamp": "2019-12-17T21:24:25.220000+01:00", "_descriptive": "LIME Pro - 6 anv\u00e4ndare", "_updateduser": 1701, "_createduser": 1, "_createdtime": "2016-09-15T10:16:26.693000+02:00", "_links": {"limetype": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limetype/deal/", "name": "deal"}, "self": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1016/"}, "relation_person": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1016/person/", "name": "person"}, "relation_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1016/document/", "name": "document"}, "relation_coworker": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1016/coworker/", "name": "coworker"}, "relation_company": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1016/company/", "name": "company"}, "relation_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1016/history/", "name": "history"}, "relation_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1016/todo/", "name": "todo"}, "relation_todo2": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1016/todo2/", "name": "todo2"}, "new_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1016/document/new/"}, "new_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1016/history/new/"}, "new_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1016/todo/new/"}}}, {"dealstatus": {"id": 15101, "key": "agreement", "text": "4. Agreement"}, "value": 10000.0, "quotesent": null, "expecteddate": null, "closeddate": "2020-04-09T00:00:00+02:00", "person": 1016, "coworker": 1003, "wonlostreason": "", "company": 1014, "name": "20 cykelkomponenter", "probability": 1.0, "weightedvalue": 0.0, "todo2": null, "_id": 1017, "_timestamp": "2021-09-18T00:45:33.483000+02:00", "_descriptive": "20 cykelkomponenter", "_updateduser": 1701, "_createduser": 1, "_createdtime": "2016-09-15T10:16:26.817000+02:00", "_links": {"limetype": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limetype/deal/", "name": "deal"}, "self": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1017/"}, "relation_person": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1017/person/", "name": "person"}, "relation_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1017/document/", "name": "document"}, "relation_coworker": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1017/coworker/", "name": "coworker"}, "relation_company": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1017/company/", "name": "company"}, "relation_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1017/history/", "name": "history"}, "relation_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1017/todo/", "name": "todo"}, "relation_todo2": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1017/todo2/", "name": "todo2"}, "new_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1017/document/new/"}, "new_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1017/history/new/"}, "new_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1017/todo/new/"}}}, {"dealstatus": {"id": 15101, "key": "agreement", "text": "4. Agreement"}, "value": 333000.0, "quotesent": null, "expecteddate": null, "closeddate": "2019-01-01T00:00:00+01:00", "person": 1021, "coworker": null, "wonlostreason": "", "company": 1018, "name": "Nytt CRM-system med reklammatinoer f\u00f6r HBA", "probability": 1.0, "weightedvalue": 333000.0, "todo2": null, "_id": 1018, "_timestamp": "2019-12-17T21:34:33.240000+01:00", "_descriptive": "Nytt CRM-system med reklammatinoer f\u00f6r HBA", "_updateduser": 1701, "_createduser": 1, "_createdtime": "2016-09-15T10:16:26.973000+02:00", "_links": {"limetype": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limetype/deal/", "name": "deal"}, "self": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1018/"}, "relation_person": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1018/person/", "name": "person"}, "relation_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1018/document/", "name": "document"}, "relation_coworker": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1018/coworker/", "name": "coworker"}, "relation_company": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1018/company/", "name": "company"}, "relation_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1018/history/", "name": "history"}, "relation_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1018/todo/", "name": "todo"}, "relation_todo2": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1018/todo2/", "name": "todo2"}, "new_document": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1018/document/new/"}, "new_history": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1018/history/new/"}, "new_todo": {"href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/1018/todo/new/"}}}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `get_api_data` returns JSON string or a dictionary - if it is a json string you will need one extra step of `json.loads(response)` before the rest of the code.

Getting specific part of a dictionary is easy, assuming it has static structure.

Relevant part of the dictionary:

```
response = {
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "https://api-test.lime-crm.com/api-test/api/v1/limeobject/deal/?_offset=10"
        }
    },
    "_embedded": {
        "limeobjects": [
            {
                "dealstatus": {
                    "id": 15101,
                    "key": "agreement",
                    "text": "4. Agreement"
                },
                "value": 500000.0,
                "quotesent": "2016-08-25T00:00:00+02:00",
...
```

We can access the values of one of `limeobjects` using `response["_embedded"]["limeobjects"][0]["value"]`

Similiarly you can extract all the values with, for example, list comprehension.